# PHP Even and ODD items in one of two columns, put first item in even column

Tags: php, wordpress

My count loop currently works but it is not working correctly. I need every second item to go into the right column and the rest stay in the left. So 1, 3, 5 etc in the column called split-left and 2, 4, 6 to go into the column called split-right

```
<!-- SPLIT EFFECT PAGE BUILDER -->
<div class="page-builder">

<?php if( have_rows('split_effect_page_builder') ): ?>
  <div class="split-left">
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  <?php while ( have_rows('split_effect_page_builder') ) : the_row(); ?>

  <?php get_template_part('template-parts/page', 'builder'); ?>

  <?php
    if($i % 2 == 0){
      echo '</div><div class="split-right">';
      $i = 0;
    } 
    $i++; 
  ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php else : ?>

<?php // no layouts found ?>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- END SPLIT EFFECT PAGE BUILDER -->
```

Comment: What, specifically is not working right?  What is happening that you don't expect to happen?

Comment: Well right now its not adding 1, 3, 5 into split-left div and 2, 4, 6 into split-right. When i inspect the result its adding 1 into split-left (this is correct) but then it adds 2 also into split-left, 2 is even and then after that it adds 3 into the split-right column, so everything is jumbled.

Comment: if i use: ($i % 2 == 0) it adds a 2nd split-right wrapper and duplicates 2 of the items.

Comment: I updated the code so its more simplified also updated it to ($i % 2 == 0) {. So inside the get_template_part is the content being looped, so just imagine a normal php while loop.

Comment: Why can you not use a normal array and then `foreach($rows as $i => $row) { ..etc.. }`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just need to reset your counter whenever it reaches 2..

```
 <?php
if($i == 2){ 
  echo '</div><div class="split-right">';
  $i =0;  // set back to zero...
} 
  $i++; // and now it's 1 again so next iteration would be left aligned
  ?>
```

PS.. not sure why you close a PHP tag only to immediately re-open it.. That won't break anything, but probably a good habit to get rid of.

Comment: I am a front-end developer, it bothers me if i dont close and open, but you have a point. You suggestion isnt working, it actually just ends up adding a 2nd split-right column?

Comment: I just need all odd number to be in the split left and all even numbers to be in the split-right column